# How to access Joomla custom component administration without full admin rights

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I need to realize a protected area for my components admin tools; i would like to use admin login and let the connected users see my admin tools without letting them access Joomla administrator stuff. How can i do it?

Comment: What I understand from your question is that you want to create an interface to moderate your component and you want your users to have access to that, but you don't want them to access `administrator` interface. Am I right?

Comment: @faridv yes, that's right. I would like to give my users to login, access my admin components but not all the joomla administration site interface

Comment: You can do that by using ACL, create a group that only has the exact rights that you want them to have and assign those users to that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Elin has stated Joomla's ACL will take care off this for you.
The groups and Access Levels are found in Users config area.  Once you have set that up, you will need to set the appropriate security access settings in the Global Configuration > Permissions settings.  This will allow them in to the Admin area and then for each of the individual components/sections/areas that you DON'T want them to have access to, you will need to make appropriate selections(look for 'Options' in each area).  Permissions are inherited and you have given them access to the Admin area in the Permissions settings above, so everything is open until you close them down.

Obvious warnings of testing  thoroughly and backing up as you're potentially opening up your system.  The ACL can become very confusing very quickly.